# AngularMaterial: md-tabs out of order if setup during http request

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-material

My view:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl"> 
          <span ng-repeat="problem in problems">{{$index}}</span>
          <md-tabs md-selected="selectedTabIndex" md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
              <span ng-repeat="problem in problems" class="panel-heading">
                {{$index}}
                <md-tab label={{$index}}> </md-tab>
              </span>
          </md-tabs>
    </div>
```

The **problems** data is coming from an http request via Controller/Service:

```
 MyService.fireRequest()
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.problems = MyService.getProblems();
     },function(data){
        // error case
   });
```

Resulting output:
[image]

As can be seen, `{{$index}}` value outside the tabs is fine, but inside the tabs, it's out of order. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: if you add `console.log($scope.problems)` after the `$scope.problems` assignment, what is output? (I'm wondering what exactly `MyService.getProblems()` returns...)

Comment: That is an array of objects

Comment: what version of material-design are you using?

Comment: The latest stable: 0.9.4

Comment: have you tried removing the `span` surrounding `md-tab`? (and putting the ng-repeat in the `md-tab`) -- I'm wondering if that `span` is confounding the `mb-tabs` behavior...

Comment: That corrected the order !!
However, now content of each tab is coming one below the other instead of side-by-side...

Comment: are you viewing on mobile or desktop?

Comment: Macbook, This is my new code for which tabs are coming one below the other: 
<md-tabs md-selected="selectedTabIndex" ng-repeat="problem in problems"  md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
            <md-tab label={{$index}}>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>

Comment: try putting the `ng-repeat` inside the `md-tab` rather than `md-tabs` (see my answer below).   I'm don't think `ng-repeat` is supported yet in `md-tabs` (https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1107)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<span>` between the outer `md-tabs` and the inner `md-tab` might be messing with the material design functionality, try putting the `ng-repeat` directly in the `md-tab` element and dropping the inner `span` element...

```
<md-tabs md-selected="selectedTabIndex" md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
    <md-tab ng-repeat="problem in problems" class="panel-heading" label={{$index}}> </md-tab>              
</md-tabs>
```